# Is there a way to check if pipelining is enabled in php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to check if pipelining is enabled in php or javascript?
There are certain services in the browser you can access in about:config that speed up the browser without uncertainty so I wanna check if some of these are or even get the value aas a string if needed in php or javascript, is this possible?
If it is possible in jQuery I would be please too ask for a reference.

Mozilla browser

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if it is possible in jQuery it is possible in "plain" JavaScript: jQuery is "just" some fancy JavaScript code, so it can't do anything JavaScript can't do.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that makes you want to know this?

Answer (score 1):

Reading out about:config from JS would be a really really big privacy/security bummer! I presume you can do a timing attack perhaps: load a bunch of images which are PHP generated and check the order they are landing on the server. It will be unreliable a little because even if HTTP request A is started before request B the networking latencies might just differ and swap the order but you can make a fairly good guess I think if you load enough images. Ie, if the request order looks like A-B-C-D-E-F and PHP sees B-A-C-D-E-F then it's not pipelined bu if you see A-D-B-E-C-F then it's likely.